# What should my nginx.conf look like for serving static content

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following content in my `nginx.conf` and everything else is as is

```
server {
    listen       8081;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    #location / {
        #root   html;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
    #}

    location = /console {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:7001/main/console;
        proxy_set_header        Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        auth_basic "Admin Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Now when I launch `http://localhost:8081/console` it successfully launches the webpage and even asks me for password.

But there are some static content in this location `/main/resources/org/nett/main/images/jquery-3.1.1.min.js`

When I click on this it throws `404`. What should be in my `nginx.conf` to serve the static content inside `/main/resources/org/nett/main/images/` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll note that the location of the static content, `/main/resources...`, doesn't match any of your locations.  .  `resources` is not under `/main/console`, and therefore there's no way to access it under your existing `proxy-pass` location.

Reconsider whether you need to change the path of your proxy.  It can be done, but requires additional configuration.  If you merely redirect `/` to `7001:/`, then when the data at `/main/console` refers to `/main/resources`, that will also have a valid proxy path through nginx.

If your definition of 'working' means the `/console` maps to `7001/main/console`, you'll have to expand upon that definition to address also how you want to map requests under `/main/<anythingelse>`, more of which may have yet to be uncovered. You'll also have to handle rewriting the references to itself the application sends back ( if, for example, more is requested from `/main/console`, it will have the same problem as stuff under `/main/resources`, because it, too, doesn't match `/console`.  URL rewrites at the proxy should only be undertaken with a decent grasp of regular expressions and http, and only with a sincere and practiced willingness to RTFM.  its complicated.

By the by, if you're attempting to add basic auth to whatever's on `7001`, make sure to also encrypt your connection (HTTPS), otherwise your credentials are plaintext on the network (http://mark-kirby.co.uk/2013/how-to-authenticate-apis-http-basic-vs-http-digest/).

Comment: Thanks I did what you said and it's working fine now :)